# Use a string as property name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to set values into text boxes by referring to them as strings

The text box names all follow a format:
eg. `txt_N1` or `txt_N2`

I want to be able to go through the text boxes by incrementing the integer of the text box name, which would look like `"txt_N" & CStr(intRow)`.

I am not sure how I am meant to go about doing this.
Below is what I've got so far

```
intRow = 1  'The 1st Row 
recVat.MoveFirst 'Go to the 1st record in the recordset

'Loop through the records
Do Until intRow = 4 Or recVat.EOF             

    'Set the text boxes in the VAT Summary
    strNet = "txt_N" & CStr(intRow)

    Me!strNet = recVat![SumOfnet_t]       


    'Move to the Next Record
    recVat.MoveNext
    intRow = intRow + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use the bang notation, but the normal notation, and this should be rather easy:

```
  Me.Controls(strNet).Value = recVat![SumOfnet_t]
```